# cp: cannot stat 'nonautilusplease/nautilus-browser.desktop'

Tags: xubuntu, nautilus, filemanager

After installing Xubuntu and restoring `/home` from previous Ubuntu install, I had some issues with opening files. So I installed nautilus. Then nautilus took control and became my default file manager, which I  did not intended.

So I removed nautilus, made sure that thunar is installed, and followed [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DefaultFileManager) I created `defaultthunar`.

However when I run `./defaultthunar`, I get 
`

```
Changing to application launcher directory


Restoring backup files

cp: cannot stat 'nonautilusplease/nautilus-browser.desktop': No such file or directory
```

The guid says:

> Default system settings in Ubuntu are overridden by settings in hidden
>   files in a user's home directory (~), if you want to change settings,
>   this is the place to do it. The files in ~/.local/share/applications

But I don't have a `~/.local/share/applications` file.

So wondering how can I fix this?

Comment: `~/.local/share/applications/` should be a directory containing many files.  It's possible that you're not displaying 'hidden' files (files with a "." as the first character are 'hidden' and not shown by default in file managers or a few commands unless told to be included eg. `ls -a` instead of `ls`).  Ensure you have 'show hidden' enabled & look again.

Comment: I checked that in terminal.